# Drools ruleset spreadsheet sequential execution

Tags: java, drools

I have many rulesets in a single spreadsheet. I am aware of a flag **sequential** but I think it ensures rules in a single RuleSet will run sequantially.

I want to ensure that all rules run in sequential order regardless of which ruleset they are in.

For example I have Rule1,Rule2 in RuleSet1, Rule3 in Ruleset2, Rule4,5 in RuleSet3.

Still my running order should be

Rule1, Rule2, Rule3, Rule4, Rule5.

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a special flag to do what you are looking for. One solution could be to use a auto-decrementing salience column to specify the rules' execution order. So:

```
Rule1 -> Salience 100 (Higher salience, higher priority)
Rule2 -> Salience 90
Rule3 -> Salience 80
...
Rule5 -> Salience 10
```

Of course this will introduce some problems when new rules are added to the spreadsheet. I would recommend you to use non-sequential numbers so you can add newer rules in between the existing ones without major problems.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks I have taken the same approach :-)